# Angular - Errors when filling a Highcharts network graph with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, loops, highcharts

I try to fill a network graph made with the JS Highcharts library (see an example in that [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/network-graph)). The whole thing is made on an Angular framework.

**I want to fill the `data` part of the graph with an array**.

When I fill directly that `data` part, the network is well built :

```
data : [
['Test 1', 'Test2'], 
['Test 1', 'Test 3']
]
```

It gives :
[image]

Now I want to fill it by using that array :

```
var myArray3 = [['Test 1', 'Test2'], ['Test 1', 'Test 3']];
```

So I write in the `data` part...

```
data : [myArray3]
```

... which gives a strange network graph.. I should have 3 nodes and two lines which is not the case.
What's more, as you can see, I get the couples (Test1,Test2)/ (Test1,Test3) instead of Test1, Test2 and Test3.
[image]

How could I do to make my graph work with the data taken from my array `myArray3` ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrapped your myArray3 unnecessarily in the brackets.
The below will work:

```
var myArray3 = [['Test 1', 'Test2'], ['Test 1', 'Test 3']];
...
data : myArray3
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0rnfdjaz/6/

Comment: My bad... I checked many combinations but not this one... it works, thank you very much @Arkadiusz ! First post on Stack Overflow and nice one :)